# Getting values from checkboxes even when they're not checked?

Tags: html, vbscript

So I'm making an html document to bascially display the uses of some principles. But, I can't get past the 1st section that requires me to check to make sure atleast one of the dummy checkboxes is checked. Sounds easy enough. Except, even when they're unchecked I'm getting values. I don't know why, I'm sure its just something I'm doing. I just don't know what.

I created the loop to just see what was being passed by checkbox "ch1" - when the box is checked, it returns yes and when it isn't check it returns yes. Mind. Blown.

```
<html>
<body>


<script language="vbscript">
<!--
Sub sarah
Set lucy = document.alice

if lucy.ch1.value="yes" then
msgbox(lucy.ch1.value)
end if


End sub
-->

</script>

<h1><center>Assignment #2</center></h1>
<br>
<br>
<form name="alice">

<br>
<br>
<b>Checkboxes</b><br>
Check 1<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" value="yes">
Check 2<input type="checkbox" name="ch2" value="yes">
Check 3<input type="checkbox" name="ch3" value="yes">
Check 4<input type="checkbox" name="ch4" value="yes">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="butler" value="EDIT and REPORT" onClick="sarah"><br>

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: VBScript? I hope you know you will only have IE support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically they all have a value of yes.  You want to check their "checked" state.

```
if lucy.ch1.checked == true
```

Comment: I edited the checkbox to <input type="checkbox" name="ch1"> and reduced the sub to soley outputting a msgbox with the value of "ch1" and every time, even when unchecked, it returns "on". What am I not getting right?

Comment: I also renamed all of the checkboxes I'm using for this section from a sequential ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4 to all ch1 to see if that would make a difference and gave them all unique values. Nope, now it doesn't return a box at all.

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution with Jquery, not sure if you are allowed to use that but this should help

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/BTGDx/

Comment: It works for sure, but I'm restricted to using VBScript for this portion of the assignment. I still haven't figured out what the problem is.